# how to get tab change event nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

Is there a way to listen for tab changes within my app-component?

```
//app.component.ts

import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-component',
        templateUrl: 'app.component.html' 
    })
    export class AppComponent {

         //this isn't working
         onSelectedIndexChanged(args) {
           console.log("changing");
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To handle `TabView` index change you can use `selecedIndexChangeEvent`. for Example:

app.component.html

```
<TabView #tabView (selectedIndexChanged)="tabViewIndexChange( tabView.selectedIndex)" class="example-container">
<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Profile', iconSource: '~/icon.png'}" >
        <ListView [items]='items'>
            <template let-item='item'>
                <Label [text]='item.itemDesc' ></Label>
            </template>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Stats'}">
        <Label text="Second tab item"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Settings'}">
        <Label text="Third tab item"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

app.component.ts

```
public tabViewIndexChange(result){
       alert("Tab View selected index: "+result);
   }
```

For further help you could review the sample app [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/master/app/ui/tab-view/tab-view-items)

Comment: The function doesn't seem to ever get called when I switch tabs. Copied directly from the sample you gave. I'm using iOS 10 though...Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Justin, I edit the example, I made a mistake with event name. Now everything should work.